# How to reference outer field inside a JOIN?

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

This is my schema:
[image]

I need to select all users with most prioritized phone and address. This is a query for selecting the most prioritized phone for a specific user(id=1):

```
select ph.id, ph.number from VisitingCard vc
left join Phone ph on ph.card_id = vc.id
where vc.person_id = 1
order by priority desc
limit 1
```

Below is my try to get to get the most prioritized phone for all users:

```
select * from Person p
left join (
    select ph.id, ph.number from VisitingCard vc
    left join Phone ph on ph.card_id = vc.id
    where vc.person_id = p.id -- no such column: p.id
    order by priority desc
    limit 1
)
```

[Link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/098f5/9) - SqlFiddle with schema and most prioritized address and phone for the user(id=1)

How can I use such queries for each user, but not only for the user with id=1?

Comment: What about ties (two number with the same, highest priority)? Should all of them be included in the result or only one? If only one is there a second criteria to choose the one or choose just any one?

Comment: @stickybit only one. It really doesn't matter which one

Comment: Learn what left join on returns: inner join on rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls. A where that requires a right table column to be not null after a left join on, which you have, removes any rows extended by nulls, ie leaves only inner join on rows, ie "turns outer join into inner join". Always know what inner join you want as part of a left join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query each user with prioritized address and phone using a correlated subquery
(thanks for the idea to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50907856/8154851)):

```
select p.*,
(
    select ph.number
    from VisitingCard vc
    left join Phone ph on ph.card_id = vc.id
    where vc.person_id = p.id
    order by ph.priority desc, ph.id asc
) as most_prioritized_number,
(
    select ad.address_text
    from VisitingCard vc
    left join Address ad on ad.card_id = vc.id
    where vc.person_id = p.id
    order by ad.priority desc, ad.id asc
) as most_prioritized_address
from Person p
```

[SqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/098f5/14)

Answer (score 1):

One method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select vc.person_id,
       (select ph.number
        from Phone ph 
        where ph.card_id = vc.id
        order by ph.priority desc
        limit 1
       ) as number
from VisitingCard vc;
```